# get previous month from sysdate and store it as a number

Tags: sql, oracle, date

please help ..how to get previous month from sysdate and store it as a number in a variable ?
i tried this but its resulting in invalid number .

```
select to_number(to_char(add_months(sysdate, -1) ,'mm')) into l_date from dual
```

this returns 12 which is desired .

But when l_date is executing in

```sql
if l_date in (1,3,5,7,8,10,12)
then
do thisss
end if;
```

in this block its failing with invalid number while comparing which i guess is not taking it a number but string or char .

Comment: Now that you've edited the code to add the missing comma, your code works [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d6f9d50b8d7f22d8780df77ecc1fad66). If you are saying that it raises an exception then please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with a description of how you are calling the code and the details of the exception that is raised.

Comment: done . added the further issue. could you please check and help .thank youu

Comment: From your comments, the error appears to come from a different line of code and not the line you have posted. Please [edit] your question with the complete PL/SQL block and the full error message and indicate which line of the PL/SQL the error message references (if it isn't obvious).

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0140d530d51c3d2626b3ff5af8037ae4) Still cannot replicate your error.

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like this:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    l_prev_month number(2);
  3  begin
  4    l_prev_month := to_number(to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - 1, 'mm'));
  5    dbms_output.put_line('Previous month = ' || l_prev_month);
  6
  7    if l_prev_month in (1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12) then
  8       dbms_output.put_line('Do this');
  9    else
 10       dbms_output.put_line('Do that');
 11    end if;
 12  end;
 13  /
Previous month = 12
Do this

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

- line #4:

  - `trunc(sysdate, 'mm')` return first-of-the-current-month
  - subtracting `1` from it returns last day in the previous month
  - apply `TO_CHAR` with the `mm` format mask to it, to get desired result

Comment: thank you , it worked but when this value is getting compared in if why its throwing invalid number errror. updated the post with if block and error .

Comment: You're welcome. If you got the error, you did something wrong. I edited my message and included `IF` - it works OK. Have  a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma between `SYSDATE` and `-1` and you don't need to convert to a string and back:

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT( MONTH FROM ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -1 ) )
INTO   l_date
FROM   DUAL
```

or, without the context switch from PL/SQL to SQL:

```
l_date := EXTRACT( MONTH FROM ADD_MONTHS( SYSDATE, -1 ) )
```

or, if you want to fix your code and convert date to string to number then just add the missing comma:

```sql
select to_number(to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1) ,'mm')) into l_date from dual;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b9e9d3d069085af818ca32eaa1534902)

Comment: worked same way as mine to return 12 but in further steps throwing invalid number error .updated the post with further code lines

Answer (score -2):

select to_number(to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1), 'mm')) from dual;

Comment: This is not getting the previous month, it is getting the month of the previous day (which for all days except the first of the month will get the current month).

Comment: add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1), 'mm') will get previous month

Comment: thank you . but its giving me the same error as invalid number when executing the if l_date in (1,3,5,7,12) and 12 is what is getting stored in l_date . Seems its not storing it in number but char /string format

Comment: try this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a8c22186eded65d658728395a01f57ec)